# send email with mailgun in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mailgun

I want to send mail with mailgun api in angular(version 1.5.8).
code following:

```
    var mailgunUrl = "sandbox459d327de2c64c7ab972c130a9747e87.mailgun.org";
    var mailgunApiKey = window.btoa("api:key-a34dcbe00b80094eae7a0cba9d5fc040");

    var requestHeaders = {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + mailgunApiKey,
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, x-requested-with",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    }

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
        data: JSON.stringify({from:'postmaster@sandbox459d327de2c64c7ab972c130a9747e87.mailgun.org',to:'sh.omidrashidi@gmail.com',subject:'test of pstar',text:'OK'}),
        headers: requestHeaders
    });
```

but i recieve error of request:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox459d327de2c64c7ab972c130a9747e87.mailgun.org/messages. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I send email with postman successfully, but with $http angular get error.
how to resolve the problem ?

Comment: If you're using chrome, install this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi to enable CORS.